# IIS Express + HttpPlatformHandler crash when launching ASP.NET 5 RC1 application

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, iis-express

After an upgrade from ASP.NET 5 beta 7 to RC1 an attempt to launch the web appplication in IIS Express from within Visual Studio ends with "An error occurred attempting to determine the process id of the DNX process hosting your application".

In Windows Event Log I can see following errors:

- Process '1828' failed to start. Port = 31115, Error Code = '-2147024891'. (EventID 1000; this happens always)
- Warning: Could not create stdoutLogFile \?\C:_temp_httpplatform-stdout.log_6072_2015128124832.log, ErrorCode = -2147024864. (EventID 1004; this happens only sometimes)

Log files as configured in the [HttpPlatformHandler Configuration](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/httpplatformhandler/httpplatformhandler-configuration-reference) do get created but are completely empty, as well as VS Output window.

How can I diagnose the reason for the failure?

Relevant versions are:

- Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 1
- DNX SDK version: 1.0.0-rc1-update1
- Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 (64-bit)

Relevant sections from web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
  </handlers>
  <httpPlatform processPath="%DNX_PATH%" 
                arguments="%DNX_ARGS%" 
                stdoutLogEnabled="true" 
                stdoutLogFile="C:\_temp\_httpplatform-stdout.log"
                startupTimeLimit="3600" 
                forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

What's perhaps also interesting is that initially when I tried to run a brand new ASP.NET 5 Web Application created from template, it worked. Now it doesn't either.

**UPDATE**: Despite the error IIS Express starts, but returns 502.3 Bad Gateway error

Comment: Try setting stdoutLogFile to just `c:\temp\`

Comment: Probably something else is running on this port. Run `netstat -a -n -o` - this will show you ports being used and PID of the process using the port. Find your port and then use PID to figure out what process it is. Or try a different port...

Comment: Make sure that "C:\_temp\" exists

Comment: @Boyarincev of course C:\_temp exists - as I said the log files are created, but empty.

Comment: @Pawel i've verified this

Answer (score 1):

So, one coworker had a similar problem.

I ended up checking the .vs\config\applicationhost.config file under the project. His turned out to have a bad < sites> section. Two of the sites were binding https to "*:44300:localhost".  I removed one (the one that also bound http to 80), renumbered the sites, and his IIS Express now works.

Comment: Well, i've found 4 sites there - one was a certain WebSite1 and then 3 sites for my project (with different ports). I have cleaned that, so that there is only one entry with id=1 and binding to http and "*:1477:localhost", however the behavior stays the same...

Comment: Well, my good one ended up having 2 sites: WebSite1 and my project.  I wonder if you removed too much.

Comment: Also, the one site that was good pointed to my project's wwwroot

Comment: I deleted .vs and let it recreate from scratch so that it was like you said, but even that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this issue for my sites ("An error occurred attempting to determine the process id of the DNX process hosting your application") - same boat, upgrading from Beta 7 to RC1.  I believe these projects were originally created in Beta 4 or 5.

It turns out there was extra garbage in my web.config from earlier versions of the ASP.Net beta, and these were mucking up the request.

I removed these:

```
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

And the sites began running appropriately in IIS Express.  If this doesn't work for you, you might try creating a new project and seeing if it works correctly - compare the web.config, startup, and project.json files to see if there are any other changes you need to make.

Comment: Actually, my only handler in the `system.webServer` section is `httpPlatformHandler` ... so no joy with this solution either ...

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem when i started project via IIS Express. I got "An error occurred attempting to determine the process id of the DNX process hosting your application". I tried repair VS, reinstall IIS but nothing worked. And next day morning i found solution on [asp toling known issues](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/blob/master/known-issues.md). Just reinstall ASP.NET 5 RC1.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.

In the `project.json` file. My code was

```
"version": "1.0.0-rc1-update",
```

I change it to

```
"version": "1.0.0-rc1-update1",
```

Because in the `launchSettings.json` file
 I have `"sdkVersion": "dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-rc1-update1"`.

It must match the sdk version in launchSettings.json file.