# 1.0.0-rc1-update: An error occurred attempting to determine the process id of the DNX process hosting your application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

My project.json

```
    {
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-rc1-update",
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
    "jqGridWebApi": "1.1.4",
    "EnyimMemcached": "2.13.0",
    "xunit": "2.2.0-beta1-build3239",
    "Moq": "4.2.1510.2205",
    "NLog": "2.1.0",
    "CryptSharpOfficial": "2.1.0",
    "System.Linq.Dynamic": "1.0.4"
  },
  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5001",
    "kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Kestrel --server.urls http://localhost:5005"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.configuration": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.Data": "4.0.0.0"
      },
      "dnxcore50": { }
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
  },
  "configurations": {
    "Staging": { }
  }
}
```

My launchSettings.json file is:

```
    {
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5001/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNET_ENV": "Development"
      },
      "sdkVersion": "dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-rc1-update1"
    },
    "web": {
      "commandName": "web",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost:5005",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "Hosting:Environment": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My web.config is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="%DNX_PATH%" arguments="%DNX_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="true" startupTimeLimit="3600" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

By the way, the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33166403/an-error-occurred-attempting-to-determine-the-process-id-of-the-dnx-process-host) is not working for my case. I tried all. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An error occurred attempting to determine the process id of the DNX process hosting your application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33166403/an-error-occurred-attempting-to-determine-the-process-id-of-the-dnx-process-host)

Comment: @blowdart, as I mentioned in the post. The link doesn't work for me.(delete project.lock.json)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS Express + HttpPlatformHandler crash when launching ASP.NET 5 RC1 application](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34156610/3757876)

Comment: Ah that was hard to see, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. In the project.json file. My code was

```
"version": "1.0.0-rc1-update",
```

I change it to

```
"version": "1.0.0-rc1-update1",
```

It must match the sdk version in `launchSettings.json` file.